# Changing back stack activity button state

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to change the state of a button (checked or not) from a CountDownTimer.

- I start the timer on the first activity.
- Then I'll go to the next activity, wait the timer to finish
- Then I'll go back.

ActivityA -> start timer -> ActivityB -> wait timer to finish -> back to ActivityA. This works.

Now, if I do the same but with one extra activity, like:

ActivityA -> start timer -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> wait timer to finish -> back to ActivityB -> back to ActivityA. This won't work, the button is still active even tho the timer was supposed to set the button to not active.

I don't know what I'm missing, but appreciate any comments on it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Show what you have tried yourself. Help community to help you

Comment: @AlexYu ty, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can finish all activities after a particular time by starting handler in Activity A:-

```
private void startTimer(){
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }, 10*1000); // timer for 10 secs
}
```

Comment: Ty, could you explain a bit more about it? Do I need to finish the activity instead of using the back button?

Comment: Please not finish() ActivityA and use this activity as MainActivity, B and C activities can be finish-able

Comment: Ty again for the response! That's what's confusing me a bit, my activity is not being finished (if I understand correctly), It's only being paused, but it's still in the stack.